# Python graphics 'int' object has no attribute 'clone'

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, zelle-graphics

```
from graphics import *      

textEntry = Entry(150, 15)
```

I'm trying to learn Python Graphics (Zelle), and i'm trying to figure out how to create a text entry box where the user can input text that I can then take to determine some things, for example, asking the user what dimensions they want on the graphics window.

It's telling me

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

With little to no background on python graphics I have no idea what this means, can anybody help me out with this and show me how to make a text entry box sort of thing in graphics to get input from a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Entry` takes a center point and a width as parameters, your first parameter is not a point, it's an int.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Now I am trying to use the entry box to get text from the user and be able to get that text and manipulate it as I wish. (Such as draw it on the graphics window, search for it in a list, etc.) I edited my question, I would really appreciate if you could take a look!

Comment: Sorry, the 90 minute wait time was killing me :(, trying to figure this out as quickly as possible

Answer (score 1):

`Entry` doesn't take 2 arguments of `int`, but a `Point` and an `int`.

> **Entry(centerPoint, width)**
>
> Constructs an Entry having the given center point and width. The width
>   is specified in number of characters of text that can be displayed.

Something like:

```
Entry(Point(233, 200),10)
```